# Converting Csv to json in chile/name format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to use Python to turn data from a CSV into a JSON with the format found here: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1093025 so that I can modify some http://d3js.org/ examples.

I have found some posts on how to do similar transformations, but nothing exactly like the nested {'name': name, 'children' = []} format.

I tried out following code but that gives me error

Following is my csv

```
L1  L2                L3        SIZE
CB  CB Current Acct Tween/Youth 10
CB  CB Current Acct Students    20
```

Following is the code written:

```
import json
import csv

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, size=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        self.size = size

    def child(self, cname, size=None):
        child_found = [c for c in self.children if c.name == cname]
        if not child_found:
            _child = Node(cname, size)
            self.children.append(_child)
        else:
            _child = child_found[0]
        return _child

    def as_dict(self):
        res = {'name': self.name}
        if self.size is None:
            res['children'] = [c.as_dict() for c in self.children]
        else:
            res['size'] = self.size
        return res


root = Node('Segments')

with open('C:\\Desktop\\Book1.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    p = next(reader)
    for row in p:
        grp1, grp2, grp3, size = row
        root.child(grp1).child(grp2).child(grp3, size)


print(json.dumps(root.as_dict(), indent=4))
```

But I get error  as following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Desktop/untitled/converting.py", line 34, in <module>
grp1, grp2, grp3, size = row
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

Expected output is

```
{
 "name": "Community",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "CB",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": " CB Current Acct",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Tween/Youth", "size": 10},
      {"name": "Students", "size": 20}
     ]
}
]
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list()` for reading the csv file as a list as it maintains the order and is iterable like this:

```
with open('C:\\Desktop\\Book1.csv', 'r') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
p = list(reader)
for row in range(1,len(p)):
    grp1, grp2, grp3, size = p[row]
    root.child(grp1).child(grp2).child(grp3, size)
```

Comment: @CyleySimon Glad I could help.

Comment: I have few doubts can i ask

Comment: @CyleySimon Sure!